# Java matches regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Does anybody know what this means in java:

```
testNumber.matches("^800[25-9][2-9].*$")
```

I am mainly confused with `[25-9]`.

Comment: [25-9] matches the characters 2,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html

Comment: Shows no evidence of investigation.

Comment: `[25-9]` is equal to `[5-92]` is equal to `[256789]` is equal to `[5-67-92]` is equal to `(?:2|[5-6]|7|8|9)` is equal to ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` is a subset. Any character in the brackets will match. `5-9` is a range of characters from 5 to 9. 2 is also a character. So `[25-9]` will match 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9.

Answer (score 1):

`[25-9]` means any character from `2` or `5-9`

You can get explanation of your regex by yourself from here: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl

Answer (score 1):

Here is a explaination about you Regular Expression:

**/^800[25-9][2-9].*$/**

- ^ assert position at start of the string
- 800 matches the characters 800 literally
- [25-9] match a single character present in the list below
- 2 the literal character 2
- 5-9 a single character in the range between 5 and 9
- [2-9] match a single character present in the list below
- 2-9 a single character in the range between 2 and 9
- .* matches any character (except newline)
- Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as
  possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- $ assert position at end of the string

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://regex101.com/ and https://www.debuggex.com/

```
^800[25-9][2-9].*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `800` matches the characters 800 literally
- `[25-9]` match a single character present in the list below

  - `2` the literal character 2
  - `5-9` a single character in the range between 5 and 9
- `[2-9]` match a single character present in the list below

  - `2-9` a single character in the range between 2 and 9
- `.*` matches any character (except newline)
  `*` Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `$` assert position at end of the string

In other words `[...]` is [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). It means it matches one of characters placed inside it like `[123]` means it matches either `1` `2` `3`. You can also write this range as `[1-3]`.

In case of `[25-9]` it means it will match `2` or one of digits in rage `5-9` which are `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`.